# Is my Visual Studio 2015 downloaded correctly?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm in a team which have a project in vs using mvc but after installing vs 2015 I'm getting a huge errors when running the project which I just cloned from vs online. this happened when may computer got a virus and I need to reset my OS and have to reinstall vs again but this huge errors occurred. already tried to reinstalling vs many times and even installed new version of OS (windows 10) in my pc thinking it will solve the issue but still getting the same errors all the time. Is there something need to be done before downloading vs 2015? I downloaded vs community which is free. please help, I am just new in visual studio.

Here is a quick preview from the errors I am getting.
[image: even syntax "ViewBag" is not reading]

This what happens when I open one of my references in solution explorer
[image]

I am now downloading vs 2015 community ISO version but I'm afraid I'll just ended up getting the same error again. Please help me. I will gratefully appreciate any comment. thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to confirm that you resinstalled all of your 3rd party components such as Newtonsoft.Json, and DYMO.Label.Framework. You do not mention that you did this.

If all of your components have be reinstalled, I would proceed in the following manner.

1. Create a new project (for example c# console) for scratch like Hello World.  If that works.
2. If that works, add some functionality which uses one of the .NET standard standard references such as System.Linq.
3. If steps 1 and 2 work, chances are your basic install of Visual Studio is successful.
4. Goto your original project and open Solution Explorer and expand the References Node under your project.  See if there are any errors on the listed references.  Perhaps you may need to delete and re-add some of your 3rd party references.
5. Since you mention that you are in a team, if all else fails, do a step by step comparison of your configuration with theirs.  You are bound to find a difference that could point to the cause.

Good luck.

Comment: at #4, I expand my references and seems that all of them are broken, all of them have a warning icon, and when I double click on one of the vs is telling me it can not be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet build. how will I re-add them since they are too many? thanks for you response sir

Comment: @Liky - you should have two types of references. native Microsoft which should start with System.XXX or Microsoft.XXX and then your 3rd party references. like Netwonsoft.XXX.  Can you confirm the problem is worth both or only 3rd party references?

Comment: I expect the problem is with your 3rd party components. Somehow Visual Studio cannot find them.  Did you install them after you installed Visual Studio?

Comment: I already installed the DYMO but when I click DYMO.label.Framework in Reference it's saying "This project can not be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built. Please ensure that the project is available and built"

Comment: That sounds like the source of your problem.  I would check DYMO forums, help desk as I do not have experience with it. Good Luck!!

Comment: but why is vs is saying that all the items in my references are not yet built. back when our team used DYMO, I only got DYMO related errors and works after downloading it. It seems that my vs lack something right now

Comment: I could be that you are missing something with your DYMO installation. IMHO best way to solve it is to go over the steps with a member of your team who is using it successfully.